# Can't connect MongoDB via Docker image

Tags: mongodb, docker

Here's my Docker compose file

```
    version: "2"
    services:
      web:
        build: .
        ports:
          - "3333:3333"
        depends_on:
          - mongo
      mongo:
        image: mongo
        ports:
          - "27017:27017"
```

Dockerfile

```
    FROM node:14
    # Create app directory
    WORKDIR /usr/src/app
    # Install app dependencies
    COPY package*.json ./
    RUN npm install
    # Copy app source code
    COPY . .
    #Expose port and start application
    EXPOSE 3333
    CMD [ "npm", "start" ]
```

File `server.ts`

```js
    import express from "express";
    import mongoose from "mongoose";
    import { decksRoutes } from "./routes/decks.routes";
    import bodyParser from "body-parser";
    
    const app = express();
    
    mongoose.connect('mongodb://mongo:27017/deck-of-cards')
      .catch(err => {
        console.log('err======>',err)
      })
    
    app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded())
    
    app.use(decksRoutes);
    
    app.listen(3333);
```

ERROR

```
    UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: MongooseError: Operation `decks.insertOne()` buffering timed out after 10000ms
    
    err======> MongooseServerSelectionError: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND mongo
```

It works fine when I change URL from 'mongodb://mongo:27017/deck-of-cards' to 'mongodb://localhost:27017/deck-of-cards'

Comment: Are you getting that error from running `docker-compose up`, or are you running `npm start` in a non-Docker development environment?

Comment: getting this error by `docker-compose up`

Comment: If `localhost:27017` works, then your app isn't running in a container

Comment: Can you connect to MongoDB from command line? Try to remove double quotes from ports in docker compose... not sure this valid

Comment: What does ```docker inspect mongo``` (network part) and ```docker network inspect <name from inspect mongo>``` gives output?

Comment: Thanks my issue got resolved. I was giving wrong image name in dockerfile.